# UIRefreshControl styling - Swift iOS7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uirefreshcontrol

How can you change the appearance of the UIRefreshControl to the "raindrop" style?
I looked up [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/) and it doesn't seem to have any appearance related options, although it inherits UIView/UIControl.

Also it's not centered in the tableview. I tried to align it by assigning a frame with x=0, but that didn't change it to left align.
Here is what it looks like

[image: UIRefreshControl out of place]

And this is my code:

```
// in class description
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

// in viewDidLoad()
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
//refreshControl.frame(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
tableView.addSubView(refreshControl)

func refresh(sender: AnyObject){
  println("refreshing")
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change it to the "raindrop" style. This was appearance of refresh control when Apple introduced it in UIKit (back in iOS 6) but then they switched to the current one. In fact there is almost no customization you can do with the built-in `UIRefreshControl` - just some basic text styling and color.

If you need more flexible control you either need to lookup 3rd party refresh controls or write something yourself.

Comment: I see. Do you have an idea how to atleast get it centered in the tableview?

Comment: I don't recall doing anything special about it. Are you sure your tableView frame is correct and that it occupies whole screen?

Comment: The tableview is out of the box in InterfaceBuilder and the tableview cells are all across the entire screen. I'll double check.

Comment: I added constraints for the tableview and now it's centered.